# Uploading a theme to wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm new to this. I coded a front page (HTML, CSS) that says my site is under construction in TextWrangler. I have two seperate files index.html, style.css. I want to upload these to show up on Wordpress. How do I go about doing this? I'm a bit new to web development from scratch. I've done some work editing themes, just never had to upload anything, etc. I've decided to start a portfolio and would like to get this online with a proper CMS that fits my needs. How do I go about doing this? Please let me know.

Comment: Hi TopChef! Glad you got a good answer here; just in case future WordPress questions get closed here on Stack Overflow, you might want to ask them on [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) — probably a better chance og good answers over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

That describes what files you need, how header.php, style.css and index.php work, sidebars, theme standards, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder under wp-content\themes and place all your files in there. Rename your index.html to index.php and then start reading about how to implement the wordpress loop into your code. It's the key to success for your theme.

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop